# Insert from list into array

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know how I can return an array of names currently on the leaderboard.

This is the code I have:

```js
function top10(maximumResults) {
  //store the leaderboard elements
  //check if leaderboard is less than 10
  //loop through leaderboard
  //return
  var output2 = document.getElementById("top10").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var output = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < output2.length; i++) {
    if(maximumResults.length < 10) {
      output[i] += output2[i].id;
    }
  }
    return output;
}
```

```html
<div id=leaderboard class=panel>
  <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
  <ol id=top10>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>aaadad</li>
    <li>dfghfdh</li>
    <li>dfghdfhg</li>
    <li>dfghfdh</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `textContent` property, not `id`. Also, don't subscript `output`

Comment: You don't call `top10` anywhere right now. What are you passing in as `maximumResults`?

Comment: using textContent still doesn't work. i'm using jquery to test the results

Comment: Show also the line of code in which you call that function, and how the argument you pass to it is initialised.

Comment: called using jquery testing, such as: var single = leaders(1);
    assert.equal(
      single[0],
      "one",
      "one correctly returned as it is at the top of the leaderboard."
    );

Comment: I don't see any call of `top10` in that. If  `leader` is supposed to `top10`, then the argument type is different - it has no `length` property. Can you provide consistent code?

Comment: sorry i didn't mean jquery i meant junit testing; the code i gave above

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the `li` values into an array with this line of code:

```
return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#top10>li'), li => li.textContent)
```

If the intention is to limit that result array to `maximumResults` elements, then you can use `slice`:

```
return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#top10>li'), li => li.textContent)
            .slice(0, maximumResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with react very easy, but in this case all you need is some jquery!:

```
var array = [1, 2, 4, 5, ,6 ,7 ,8] /// here you can update with own elements

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         $("ol").append("<li>" + array[i] + "</li>")
         }
  })
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/n5phf/405/