# Javascript - reading html list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read this html list:

```html
<div id="leaderboard" class="panel">
  <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
  <ol id=top10>
    <li>yeah</li>
    <li>grgsdg</li>
    <li>dfhdfhdfh</li>
    <li>Ttest</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<script>
console.log(leaders());
 function leaders() {
  //store the leaderboard elements
  //check if leaderboard is less than 10
  //loop through leaderboard
  //return
  var output2 = document.getElementById("top10").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var output = [];

  for(var i = 1; i < output2.length; i++) {
    //if(maximumResults.length < 10) {
    //output2[i] = output[i];
      output.push(output2[i].textContent);
    //}
  }
    return output;
}
</script>
```

This is what i have so far:

however, it only outputs the element index (0, 1, 2, 3) etc.. instead of the actual strings inside the list

Comment: set i to 0. var i = 0;

Comment: Your use of live snippets is pointless when you separate your JS into a different snippet to the HTML it needs to work (and when you don't provide a means to call the JS function).

Comment: How's this question different from [your last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390298/insert-from-list-into-array)?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with 0 as array starts from 0
Use this function

```
for(var i = 0; i < output2.length; i++) {
    //if(maximumResults.length < 10) {
    //output2[i] = output[i];
      output.push(output2[i].textContent);
    //}
  }
```

Here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5qyu77st/

Go to the fiddle and check the console after pressing f12